# How to reference cells by positional offset when applying conditional formatting to a range of cells?

Tags: excel, offset, conditional-formatting

Suppose we have two large columns of numerical data, A and B.  If we wanted to perform a quick visual screening to determine for which rows column A's value exceeds that of column B, we could of course create a third column using some kind of conditional operator which compares the values in columns A and B, then apply conditional formatting to the new column.

But can this be done more efficiently, without the creation of a third column?  Can we use conditional formatting to simply change the background color of column A wherever it contains a value larger than the one to its immediate right in column B?

Is there a formula which evaluates to TRUE only when [this cell] > [cell to the right of this cell]?

Assume the default A1 notation is in effect.

Answer (score 1):

Use formula:

```
=$A1>$B1
```

and apply to desired range.

[image]

Comment: Thanks for the quick response.  Does $A1, in the context of the conditional formatting box, always mean 'this cell', rather than the cell whose address is actually A1?

Comment: No, A1 means the first cell relative to ```Applies to``` range, i.e. for range ```$A$1:$B$25``` it changes ```A1->A1, B1->B1``` etc. If you make absolute column ($A1) then it changes as ```A1->A1, B1->A1, A2->A2, B2->A2``` etc. And if you make absolute both row and column ($A$1) then it does not changes ```A1->A1, B1->A1, A2->A1, B2->A1``` etc.

Comment: Is there a formula which would continue to work if these cells were transplanted to a new location?

Comment: @user2790167 Of course. Any formula, any range, Just remember that formula cells are relative to the formatting range.